# Azure function ModuleNotFound error 'azure.keyvault'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am getting the error when i deploy my python function code from azure devops pipeline. When i try from VS code, I am nnot getting this error message. I've tried a solution given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61707234/10414592) and still not able to resolve it.

Comment: are you having the function in python?

Comment: Please share your code with us

Comment: @Sajeetharan - yes i have python function

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej - Sorry i am restricted to do that

Comment: Could you please share your `requirements.txt` ?

Comment: @HuryShen - please find the below names,

azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
azure-keyvault
azure-identity
pandas
pyodbc
azure-storage-file-datalake

Comment: May I know how did you deploy the function from local to azure ?

Comment: Could you please check if the `requirements.txt` was also deployed when you deploy the function from local to azure ? And please check if the `requirements.txt` exists under correct path.

Comment: @HuryShen - I am deploying the function using Azure Devops. I verified the files in the function app.. The requirements.txt file was present inside the wwwroot folder

Comment: Could you please have a try with this command `func azure functionapp publish <fun app name> --build remote` in VS code to deploy your function.

Comment: If you run the command in previous comment, azure cloud will install the modules according to `requirements.txt`. You can also try this command `func azure functionapp publish <fun app name> --build local`. This command is used to pack all of the modules from local and deploy them to cloud.

Comment: @HuryShen - From VS code, i am not getting this error. Only when i try from the devops pipeline, I am getting this error

Comment: I mean you can try to deploy your function from VS code by the commands I provided above, instead of deploy by devops.

Comment: Or your requirement is you must deploy by devops ?

Comment: I must use devops to do it

Comment: Ok, could you please share your YAML for Azure pipeline build ?

Comment: @HuryShen - I was able to resolve the issue with the  link below,
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860947/how-to-make-a-continuous-delivery-of-a-python-function-app-deployed-in-azure). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, could you please summarize the solution from the link as an answer for this post for other communities reference ?

Comment: We have a Bash script task that install the python libraries present in the requirements.txt. 

python3.6 -m venv worker_venv
source worker_venv/bin/activate
pip3.6 install setuptools
pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt

I changed the above script to a new one as mentioned below

pip3.6 install --target .python_packages/lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the solution from the comments above for other communities reference:

Op has a Bash script task that install the python libraries present in the requirements.txt.

```
python3.6 -m venv worker_venv
source worker_venv/bin/activate
pip3.6 install setuptools
pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt
```

Just change the above script to:

```
pip3.6 install --target .python_packages/lib/site-packages -r requirements.txt
```