# How to run a Python Azure Function with a private Azure Artifact dependancy

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy a Python Azure Function into an Azure Function App. The function `__init__.py` script imports an SDK which is stored as an Azure Artifact Python Package. I can build and publish the function to Azure successfully using a pipeline from the DevOps repo, however the function fails at the `import mySDK` line when I run it.

I assume the issue is that because the function is serverless, when it is called the SDK needs to be pip installed again - how do I do this?

I have tried adding a PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL to the artifact feed in the Function App with no success.

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494340/use-own-packages-artifact-in-azure-function , https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2277 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860947/how-to-make-a-continuous-delivery-of-a-python-function-app-deployed-in-azure

Answer (score 1):

`PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` wored for me.
What was the issue you received when you tried it?

Basically before you deploy your function, you should alter the application settings on your function app and add the PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL key-value pair. Then add the python package in your azure artifacts feed to the requirements.txt file in your function app code.

There is a good guide here [EasyOps - How To connect to azure artifact feed from Function App](https://www.easyops.tech/post/how-to-connect-to-private-azure-devops-artifacts-feed-from-azure-function-app)